# Explorer jumplist dissappears repeatedly

Tags: windows-7, jumplist

I've always had problems with windows 7 jump lists disappearing, but it used to be an infrequent problem. But I now have a bat-file to regularly back up all jumplists, so I can restore easily. This is probably why the Explorer jumplist fails again within a day of being restored, as it's probably related to some corrupt data in the file.

Is there any known fix for this problem?

I run Windows 7 SP1, with limited additional updates. I have about 30 Explorer jumplist items.

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following way:

1. Copy the next line to the paste board, [highlight it in blue by dragging the cursor across the line from left to right, press and hold Ctrl then press C - release both.]
   %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations
2. Open any Internet Explorer Folder.
3. In the address bar at the top, you will see an icon, usually yellow and blue by default, at the left hand end.
4. Click on that icon which will highlight everything in the address bar in blue.
5. Press and hold Ctrl then press V - release both, this will paste the line you previously copied, into the address bar.
6. Click the blue arrow at the end of the address bar.
7. A folder will have opened up, C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations.
8. Locate the file with the name - 1b4dd67f29cb1962.automaticDestinations-ms - probably the first one displayed in the folder.
9. Delete this.
10. View if Explorer jumplist recovery.

Source: [Windows 7 Explorer jump list disappeared](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8e3c2a80-392d-44e2-8b9f-6eb5deb9a1e1/windows-7-explorer-jump-list-disappeared?forum=w7itproui)

**Tip: In the above article, some people have encountered the same problem as you. There are several other methods mentioned in the article. If the above methods are not valid, I suggest you try other methods.**

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. But it is not a fix. It only restores an empty working explorer jumplist. I already have a better method of restoring the old from a backup. But the cause and an actual fix for this problem I have not seen anywhere.